# Global function visibility in different files defined in one?

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm having difficulty understanding the scope of a function inside another scripts.

Script 1 define libs:

```
define(['jquery', './lib/components/base/modal', 'https://domain.name/script_prod.js?v='+Math.random()], function($, Modal) {
    new Modal({params}); // OK: func is visible
    var CustomWidget = MyWidget;
    return CustomWidget;
});
```

Script 2 with my func:

```
    var MyWidget = function() {
        var self = this,
            system = self.system;
new Modal(Pparams}); // Error: func not visible
        return this;
    };
```

How to make function **Modal()** (from modal lib) **visible inside Script 2**?

I try define global `var modal = new Modal();` in script 1 and call in script 2 - also not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var modal = new Modal(); this will make the variable local to the module u are defining, the way to make a Modal object global is :
window.modal=new Modal();

Or create a module having following export:
exports.modal=new Modal();